# Change the status of a task - Best practice

Tags: java, spring-boot, business-process-management

I am creating an application that concern the activities to be carried out in a company.

These tasks can go through n states (e.g. new, in progress, completed, canceled).

The status step is determined by both the previous state and the user who is currently logged on.

What is the best way to handle all this in a spring boot application? A BPM engine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its as simple as you suggested, list of rules, [Drools](https://www.drools.org/) should be fine.

If its more elaborate, please have a look at [activiti](https://www.activiti.org/)

Both easily integrates with SpringBoot.